# Forward Between interfaces On Mikrotik

Tags: traffic, mikrotik

im having a trouble
ive a mikrotik router with 2 interfaces up ( let's call lan1 and lan2 ) 
Lan 1 has the IP 192.168.100.1
lan 2 192.168.0.32

Lan1 the other side of the wire goes to a cisco wich IP is 192.168.100.20 , and beside that cisco its another network with IP 10.94/16 
if i test over the mikrotik with winbox y can reach the cisco AND the other network itself,

now in my network we have the range 192.168.0.0/16 
i can ping the lan2 of the mikrotik, but cant reach lan1 or cisco or 10.94 network,

could anyone help me wich filter rules and nat rules should i create to forward the requestest from 192.168.0.0/23 and reach 10.94.0.0/16 ? or the whole traffic coming for LAN2 forward to LAN1?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Lan1 or Cisco or 10.94.x.x Don't have a route to the Lan2 network.
So you either have to write a route in cisco/10.94.x.x for the lan1 (192.168.100.0/24) or write a NAT rule in mikrotik to obtain access.

> This solution only works if mikrotik and cisco are gateways for the networks

For instance in Cisco router(config mode) you can do:

```
ip route 192.168.0.0 255.255.252.0 192.168.100.1
```

and a route in the mikrotik for 10.94 network:

```
ip route add dst-address=10.94.0.0/16 gateway=192.168.0.1
```

(I assume mikrotik IP is 192.168.0.1)

or Do a NAT in mikrotik which seems a better way like this:

```
ip firewall nat add action=masquerade chain=srcnat src-address=192.168.0.0/23
ip firewall nat add action=masquerade chain=srcnat dst-address=192.168.0.0/23
```

or even a masquerade for all to make every packet passing Mikrotik route-able :

> ip firewall nat add action=masquerade chain=srcnat

Comment: The problem is not with routing tables. The problem is with forwarding between the subnets on the mikrotik itself. From the mikrotik itself ping 192.168.100.1 with lan2 as the source interface. It doesn't work.

Likewise from the mikrotik ping tool, ping 192.168.0.32 with source interface lan1 - also doesn't work. A route entry on the mikrotik won't resolve this.